# BUG? - Attachments do not work when posting into Teams via https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{team}/channels/{channel}/chatthreads

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am using the Graph API to post a new thread into a Teams channel, using something like this as the `POST` body:

```
rootMessage: {
  body: {
    contentType: 1,
    content: 'Test content'
  },
  attachments: [{
    contentType: 'image/png',
    contentUrl: 'data:...',
    name: 'filename.png'
  }]
}
```

The message content does appear in the channel, but there is no attachment. If I `GET` the

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{team}/channels/{channel}/messages
```

then I can see my message there but attachments is `[]`.

I have also tried `contentType`: `reference` and `contentUrl`:

```
https://something.com/image.png
```

but in all cases, there is no attachment posted.

There is a typo in the Graph API docs for `chatmessage` (it says `attachment` for the key rather than `attachments`) but I am using the correct key.

Am I doing something wrong? Or, is this a known Graph API issue? Is there a workaround/fix?

Thanks! I really appreciate your help.

-Adrian

Answer (score 1):

Attachments (and rich text) are not yet supported by the POST /chatthreads API. The only way to post messages with attachments today is with our bot APIs.

We are working on write APIs to match our recently-released read APIs but they aren't ready yet. There's no need to put anything on UserVoice though.

Unfortunately I don't have a date to share, but we are actively working on them.

Answer (score 0):

> APIs under the /beta version in Microsoft Graph are in preview and are subject to change. Use of these APIs in production applications is not supported.

The returned value of **attachment** in the document is the embodiment of the product group design, and we cannot get the value should be the product group is still developing and improvementing the API. So there are no other workground at this moment.

For adding, no official docs have announced we can add attachments by Graph API. And based on my test, the try all failed too. So we need to submit a feature request in [UserVocie](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) for directly way or research by ourselves for a none-official workaround.

Comment: Seiya - just to clarify, my issue is not with anything to do with the returned value of **attachment**. My issue is that I cannot add an **attachment** to a new channel thread I create in Teams. My application does not actually require reading the chat thread and/or the returned value of **attachment**.

-Adrian

Comment: I know you want to get attachment due to you have said "POST". But no official docs have announced we can add attachments by Graph API. And based on my test, the try all failed too.